# DVI graphics card PCI-E to USB Monitor

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, graphics-card, dvi

I want to connect a 7" USB powered touch screen monitor to the DVI connector on my graphics card.
Or use the capabilities of the graphics card.
I have a video capture card with 4 cameras (PCI-E) connected to the mother board.
If I connect the USB monitor to the motherboard USB port will I be using the PCI-E graphics card or the onboard integrated graphics of the motherboard to go to the USB 7" monitor?
I want the cameras and all other graphics to use the GPU card going to the displays.
There are 4 displays 2 DVI, 1 DVI to HDMI adapted display and 1 USB powered display (touch screen monitor).
Or am I just barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 2):

You are barking up the wrong tree.
All USB monitors have a software driver that fakes an extra video-card for Windows.
The output of that video-card is send (over USB) to the monitor.
So all rendering is software based on your CPU. Therefore slow as molasses.

P.S.
This is not to be confused with touchscreen monitors that have a video-input (DVI, DisplayPort, VGA) and an USB cable.
On these devices the USB is only used to handle the touch-screen.
The Video comes from your regular GPU.

Comment: Well then I was going the wrong way on both accounts. Hope this will display the 4 camera output. Slow as molasses maybe acceptable.